# line numbers in stack trace

Tags: ios, stack-trace

The line numbers in stack traces for IOS builds do not seem to
correspond to either the original sources or the .m sources generated
by the build process.  Is there a way to interpret them ?

For example, in the trade below online_root.start:721 is refers to
a method in a file with only 111 lines.  The correspinding .m file
has only 319 lines.

*** CN1 log ****
[null] 0:0:48,666 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at online_Root.start:721
    at util_JWSApplication.runMain:216
    at util_JWSApplication.xmain:124
    at com_boardspace_BoardspaceLauncher.launchLobby:110
    at com_boardspace_BoardspaceLauncher.doit:0
    at com_boardspace_BoardspaceLauncher.run:51
    at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153

*** End of CN1 log ****

Comment: Those aren't line numbers. You need to symbolicate the crash log to get filenames and line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a platform for crashing such as HockeyApp or Crashlytics, that would be easiest way to interpret the crash logs on an iOS device.  If you don't go that route, you will need to understand the `atos` command, basically address to symbol.  There are plenty of resources here about `atos` and how to get it working, this is the route I took and works well.

Comment: You don't need `atos`. Use the `symbolicatecrash` script provided with Xcode and the command line tools. Just point it at the dSYM and the crash log. Simple.